# Links underline not showing in unordered list on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, google-chrome-devtools, html-lists

I customized my links appearance with an purple after pseudo element:

```css
body {
  background: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 60%;
  left: -0.1em;
  right: -0.1em;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: top 200ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.8, 0.13, 1);
  background-color: hsl(250, 90%, 60%);
  filter: opacity(50%);
}

a:hover:after {
  top: 0%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Projects</h2>
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://grenzlandjugend.de">Homepage of a local youth club</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://wzapp.felkru.com">WhatsApp archive reader</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://docs.v1engineering.com/mpcnc/intro/">I built a version of this CNC-Router</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://mytodoapp123.web.app/">Todo App with login and synch functionality</a></li>
</ul>
<p>
  A lot of the things I programmed recently are available on <a href="https://github.com/felkru" target="_blank">GitHub</a>, my <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/felkru">FreeCodeCamp Profile</a> or <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/18695803/felkru">Stackoverflow</a>
</p>
```

On desktop all the links work like expected (third link is in hover state):
[image: Links working as expected]

But on mobile only links within the second section of my page do not have the underline:
[image: Links not working as expected in mobile ul]

You can reproduce the problem at [www.felkru.com](http://www.felkru.com), by using any mobile device in dev tools or opening the page on your smartphone.

Why is that and how would you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It appears your a:after pseudo element is being overlapped by another element.

If you change z-index to 1 (or more) you will see the purple underline.

```
a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 60%;
  left: -0.1em;
  right: -0.1em;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: top 200ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.8, 0.13, 1);
  background-color: hsl(250, 90%, 60%);
  filter: opacity(50%);
}
```

However, this appears to make your a:after pseudo element overlap your text which might be undesirable.

Comment: @GonePhising I did not add any elements in the media query though.

Comment: In your media query when your page is less than 480px you set background to a gray color. If you remove this you can see your links.

Comment: @GonePhising How could you move the grey background behind the :after element?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the "Todo App" link on mobile or desktop. Did you remove that link?

As for the difference between how the site is acting depending on what device is viewing it: It seems you're using .htaccess or some other way to redirect to a mobile version. If you haven't added the mobile detection and scaling meta tags to the source code of the pages that might be why it's doing that.

Example, meta tags like these should be in your `<head> HERE </head>` section of every page.

I see you have these in your source code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Accept-CH" content="DPR, Width, Viewport-Width">
```

Try these:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable = yes">
```

I'm assuming it might be something with the syntax or maybe some overlapping code trying to do the same thing differently?

Comment: Yes. I removed the todo app link. The <meta http-equiv="Accept-CH" content="DPR, Width, Viewport-Width"> is purely for image hints and does not have anything to do with mobile detection as far as I know. I will give your recommendation a try and get back to you afterwards.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work for me.

Comment: my meta tags are already in the head